# f = lambda n:(1,f(n-1)*n)[n>1] gives RunTimeError in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm golfing a factorial function in Python 3, but my lambda doesn't work:

```
f = lambda n:(1,f(n-1)*n)[n>1]
```

It raises this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
# Many other identical lines...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples aren't lazily evaluated. Even though `f(0)` will select the first element in the tuple `(1, f(-1)*0)`, it still has to call f(-1) before it can do so. And before f(-1) can return, it has to call f(-2), and so on forever.

Consider using the inline conditional instead, which *does* delay evaluation until it knows which branch it's going to go down.

```
f = lambda n:1 if n <= 1 else f(n-1)*n
print f(10)
```